# Does one get academic credit towards a degree for open online courses?

Tags: degree, online-learning, mooc

Lately lots of courses like udacity, coursera, and MITx are provided online. I attended most of them; also I have attended courses in OCW provided by MIT. Now I desire to earn some credits for whatever I have learnt so far, so that I can apply for a degree (in electronics and computer engineering).

- Could anyone suggest some place where I will get accredited for the courses I do?

Comment: Hi Mona. Could you try to expand your question, and detail the different points you mention? What online course did you take, what kind of degree do you want, etc? As it is, the quality of this question is very low.

Answer (score 10):

Most of the courses that I've seen explicitly state that you obtain no credit for doing the course. More explicitly, they may offer certificates of completion, but these certificates do not convey academic credit. For example, from Coursea's [Term's of Service](https://www.coursera.org/about/terms):

> This Letter of Completion, if provided to you, would be from Coursera and/or from the instructors. You acknowledge that the Letter of Completion, if provided to you, may not be affiliated with Coursera or any college or university. Further, Coursera offers the right to offer or not offer any such Letter of Completion for a class. You acknowledge that the Letter of Completion, and Coursera’s Online Courses, will not stand in the place of a course taken at an accredited institution, and do not convey academic credit.

So the short answer is that you will be unlikely to obtain such credit. Certainly, read the terms of service to be sure. Nevertheless, you could add such things to your CV to demonstrate your interest in a particular field.

Comment: Yes Dave but what I'm asking is there a specific certification exam that can get me those credits?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Just want to warn readers that this answer (which is currently the most up voted) is no longer accurate - see [this more recent answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/12708/11365)

Answer (score 4):

There are ways to get accredited for completing online courses on Courses as of 2013.

Coursera now offers *Signature Tracks* for some courses, on completing which you get a *Verified Certificate*. In a Signature Track, on submitting each assignment, you are asked to submit some written text as well, which is verified against a handwriting sample given by you at the beginning of the course. There are other techniques used too, such as facial recognition via webcam, etc.

Also, some courses have started to provide an option to give the final exam at a certified Testing Center to earn a similar Verified Certificate.

Each of these, of course, cost money.

Comment: Do these "Verified Certificates" actually count for credits at other academic institutions, or is it just another thing to put on a CV?

Comment: When I answered, I don't think so @cpast but as of today, quite a few courses have arrangements with institutes which allow them to be taken for course credit.

Comment: Coursera has now entered at least [one agreement](https://www.coursera.org/university-programs/masters-in-computer-data-science) with a university to offer a MS with their online courses.

Answer (score 2):

There are no services to help you get that coursework accredited. However, Degreed.com helps you validate that you have taken those courses so you can let employers know.