# How do the completion of online courses impact a Master's application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, online-learning, mooc

I see places like Coursera, Udacity and EdX offer certificates upon successful completion of course work. Also most of the people doing recorded teaching at these places are famous and well known professors.

So if someone mentions those kind of course certificates in CV or application material for grad school, does it have a significant value for the applicant?

Do you consider these kind of certificates at the same level with a grade on an academic transcript?

Comment: Related questions: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2336/102, http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1317/102

Comment: I think this is different enough from earlier MOOC questions to keep open.  TMNT isn't asking about [inclusion in an academic CV](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2336/can-i-include-the-completion-of-udacity-and-coursera-classes-i-have-attended-in) (which most people have only _after_ grad school) or [getting official academic credit](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1317/academic-credit-for-online-courses) for MOOCs.

Comment: Regarding the edit, a grade based on a proctored exam could carry some weight (and I believe this is an option for some edX courses).  If it is just based on online homework or exams, then it means much less.

Comment: It will also be an issue of accreditation. The bricks and mortar coursework at those institutions is accredited. The MOOCs may not be accredited or examined during the accreditation process, especially if they are not currently counted as credit toward a degree.

Comment: @tmnt Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 10):

> So if someone mentions those kind of course certificates in CV or application material for grad school, does it have a significant value for the applicant?

They are better than nothing, but it's unlikely that they would have significant value.  Courses are only a small part of what matters for graduate admissions, and elementary or low-level courses matter the least of all.  Only a fraction of Coursera/Udacity courses are at a high enough level to matter, and even those courses aren't likely to make much of a difference.

I would not recommend devoting any time to online courses for the purpose of graduate admissions.  If they are teaching something you really want to understand and have no better opportunity to learn, then that's a good reason, but the learning will have to be its own reward.

> Do you consider these kind of certificates at the same level with a grade on an academic transcript?

I'd look at a certificate of completion for an online course the same way I'd look at a traditional course taken pass/fail (i.e., without a grade).  It's evidence that you have done something, which shows some level of motivation and energy, but it's not evidence that you actually learned much in the process.

However, there's a bigger issue than grades here.  Ultimately, good grades don't mean that much: standards vary dramatically, the ceiling is rarely high enough to distinguish between excellent students, and even if the ceiling is high enough it's not clear that this is a meaningful comparison.  Letters of recommendation are crucial for supplying the information grades alone can't supply, and this is something MOOCs are currently unable to help with.

Comment: I agree. Grad schools tend to care about your **grades** in the classes you take. If you only receive a certificate of completion, the grad school cannot tell the difference between completing the minimum required effort (which they don't want) and going above and beyond (which is what they are looking for)

Comment: Well, they do know you did *something*. Isn't that better than nothing? Also, grades mean nothing in general, and I think that is what the last paragraph of this answers says.

Comment: @Raphael: Doing something is better than nothing, but it's not much.  As for grades, if you get excellent grades in some advanced undergrad classes, it's evidence that you have a good foundation in the field.  That's valuable to know, because not having a good foundation could keep you out of grad school, but the grades themselves won't go very far towards getting you admitted.  On the other hand, a bunch of courses without grades won't even establish the solid foundation.

Comment: I still see an inherent issue with recognising "excellent grades in some advanced undergrad classes" because graders grade very differently, but what you say is true. However, I think "better than nothing" is an answer to the question. Or, if you have completed such a course, would putting it in a CV/track record ever hurt?

Comment: I don't think it would help much, if at all, but I don't think it would hurt, so I've added "better than nothing" to the answer.

Comment: I don't know if I should ask this separately or not, but how can letters of recommendation be "crucial"? No student is going to submit a letter of recommendation that speaks poorly of him, and from what I've heard professors who get asked this a lot have form letters anyway. If anything should be "crucial" shouldn't it be in-person visits/interviews?

Comment: @rocinante: Certainly applicants choose the letter writers they think will make the best possible case for them, so outright negative letters are rare, but letters still vary enormously in strength and content.  I've occasionally seen what's clearly a form letter, but that's not common (and when it does happen, the fact that it provides almost no information is bad for the applicant).  If a letter is vague or uninformative, then that itself is a problem even if the letter is supportive.

Comment: Visits/interviews are nice when they happen, but they are often not part of grad school admissions (because of time and expense).  Furthermore, letters can provide information you can't easily get from an interview.  For example, a letter from an undergraduate thesis supervisor can convey much deeper and more nuanced insight into the applicant's capabilities than anyone is likely to get from an interview.

Comment: Cost needn't be an issue at all. If the student is interested in graduate school, they can definitely afford a plane ticket to visit and see for himself the kind of people he could be working with. I find that "nuance" very hard to believe unless you happen to know the professor who wrote the letter. As a student I certainly don't think it's fair to punish students for the laziness of professors who use form letters. Letters aren't seen by the student, so they couldn't possibly know if a form letter was used. Of course it's these types of prejudices have soured me on grad school altogether.

Comment: Professors who use form letters aren't doing their job, and it's certainly unfair to their students, but fortunately I don't see this happening very often when I compare letters by the same person for different students (which happens pretty often).  As for travel costs, it's common for students to apply to five, ten, or even more grad schools, and departments may get five hundred or a thousand applications.  This makes it difficult to have interviews for anyone beyond a short list of finalists, in which case you still need to narrow it down to that list.

Comment: I certainly don't think the system we have now is perfect, and substantial improvements may be possible.  However, the current system is a response to a lot of constraints, and people have settled into it pretty well (figuring out ways to ameliorate the more pressing problems), so big changes take a lot of work to pull off.  Still, it's always worth a try...

Comment: Of course I understand the system is resistant to change, and I am certainly not expecting it to change any time soon. For myself, as my undergraduate experience wraps up, I certainly would never consider accepting an offer of admission without first meeting department members or at least sit in on one of their classes to see what they're like. I've heard enough horror stories of department politics to decide that the actuarial route is probably what I will end up doing instead of grad school.

Answer (score 6):

> I see these places offer a certificate upon succesful completion of course work.

I agree with Anonymous Mathematician. There is a difference between completion and mastery. Graduate schools need to know that you have **mastered** the prerequisite material. In the future, courses like these may count for something to graduate schools if they demonstrate and certify rigor and mastery.

Currently, these courses are targeting the Professional Development market. Many industries required or encourage their employees to further their education. For professional development, usually **completion** of the course/webinar/workshop/whatever is all that is tracked. A future employer may care that you have taken 2 or 3 MOOCs in accounting, but an MBA program would probably disregard them.

Comment: How can an admission commitee assess mastery? (That is actually a complex question, and a good answer might help to improve the certification process of MOOCs.)

Comment: In the US, presumably, if you take a course, let's say Biochemistry, at a regionally accredited institution and get whatever minimum grade (A or B) that the committee wants to see, then the committee has a reasonable idea of how much you know about biochemistry. You probably had to make high marks on exams to earn that grade. If you instead took a MOOC in Biochemistry, and received a "complete", the admissions committee remains uncertain what marks you needed on exams to achieve "completion".

Comment: I don't know about the US, but over here professors devise the exams and grade them. Therefore, an A has next to no global meaning. In reality, grades are not even comparable inside one department, let alone universities. What gets me an A there may only get me a B somewhere else. It becomes worse if you compare grades across borders. If commitees assume something about your knowledge -- or more interestingly, ability -- from the number of A's on your record (in whichever direction), they are kidding themselves.

Comment: Raphael, I agree with you, being an A+ student must be personal preference of faculty because they were also an A+ student. Even at the same department there are professors with different grading schemes. Not even talking about  U.S/E.U and other part of the world where continents are different. eDX courses will evolve into TOEFL kind of examination in future, but still there are faculty who don't care about TOEFL scores. But natural selection will sweep these faculty too, as their competitors get access to quality human resource while they are still going the old way.

Comment: @BenNorris On Coursera, if students do more than 90% get "with distinction" mark in a statement of accomplishment, at least in all the courses I finished.

Answer (score 4):

You do realize that MOOC's provide the full syllabus of their courses, and generally give a percentile ranking of the students in comparison to students from all over the world.

I'd be more skeptical about a degree/transcript from a university I have heard little about than a MOOC who's syllabus I can consider and depth which I can evaluate, in addition to the obvious motivation for learning FACT.

In addition most MOOC's clearly mention about the amount of grades they require from the students to get a Certificate of Completion.

70 % was the standard for Most Coursera courses that I completed/audited.

In addition, if Coursera is asked, they can provide (in the future) to employers information about how a student develops his code and how frequently he changes his code before committing, etc.