Will online certificates help me switch majors in grad admissions?
I am a physics bsc 2nd year in a decent(not top) Indian Uni. I now have realised that I like math more than physics and want to do a masters in math abroad. I cannot switch majors and I can only take introductory group theory and real anaysis from the math dept. (Also intro probability, diff.eq, multivar calc etc mandatory for physics. Also 2 'math methods for physics' courses.)
There is this ONLINE portal called NPTEL which offers courses with assignments, proctored exams and a certification with percentage score. The courses are offered by top public Universities in India. Will obtaining these online certificates with good score (in the needed pure math courses) help me attain admission in a good math masters program abroad?
I don't want to waste time and money for this if it is useless.
If not, what must I do? Is there no way?

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3312/how-do-the-completion-of-online-courses-impact-a-masters-application Does this answer your question?

@Allure  No,the OP in that post talked about a proctored exam course.Also the the post is very old. I would like some advice.

I agree with Allure, old as it may be, I encourage you to read the answers to the question. In particularly, anonymous mathematician's answer also addresses the point about examination and grading.

Knowledge is rarely useless so I do not want to discourage you in any way, shape, or form from learning things that are useful to your career as a Mathematician.
For graduate admissions in the United States, you need to have demonstrated capabilities. For most Mathematics departments, a strong undergraduate Physics degree is perfectly acceptable, as the mathematical skills required for the Physics degree are very comparable to the ones in Mathematics. In the US, undergraduate Mathematics classes start with Calculus and only move towards proofs towards the end. At my university, the first course with proofs is the Discrete Mathematics class, where induction proofs are taught (among other things), which is taken at the end of the second year.
Unlike the Indian system, the Western systems allow more flexibility in switching careers. Of course, a pre-law student wanting to get into a graduate program in Mathematics might face some difficulties. You can look at the GRE subject topics to see what is expected from Mathematics graduate students. You should also look at some target universities in the US and see what they require, so that would probably involve writing to the director of graduate admissions.
In my (not often very humble) opinion, you would do best to select one of these additional classes per year or semester and do well in them. This gives you an opportunity to try out your new-found interest in Mathematics, show that you are a serious student, and might allow you to get a good letter of recommendation from outside your university. But make sure that you do not drop your grades in your Physics program.
Here is what I found from UC San Diego, which is quite good:


A Bachelor's degree in Mathematics is recommended or a strong background in mathematics with a minimum GPA of 3.0 required.
A year's sequence in both upper-division algebra and real analysis is strongly encouraged.



Thank you very much. But I have some questions: 1) Will NPTEL make any considerable difference? Of course knowledge is good, but I'd much rather learn from a book than a course. Also the exam costs good fee. | 2)Are not the grad courses really competitive?Will I stand a chance against actual math majors?|3)Do you know about european, especially German public schools?

Look, you need to do your homework. Check out a few schools and see what they want.

For UCSD, Algebra and Real Analysis would be very helpful.

At least in this year, in math, in the U.S., certificates about on-line learning do not carry much weight at all, because there's not even a hint of quality control... and grad admissions people do not want to have to do research about the substance of these things.
Also, currently, these on-line certification thingies seem to be dominantly profit-driven, and, thus, have motivation to give sufficient certificates to keep people signing up. One might argue that the same is true of universities... but the admissions filter at universities' grad programs is highly non-trivial. E.g., offering to pay the tuition does not guarantee admission.

Will having a good undergrad research  profile be better than doing these courses?

Yes, undergrad research is better than certificates, at least for now... :)
