# Is an X-Series Certificate from edx useful for graduate school?

Tags: cv, mooc

I saw a similar question posted on the website, but in my opinion this one is different enough to deserve its own space.

Currently, I'm working on a self-paced online course on edX called ANUx: The Greatest Unsolved Mysteries of the Universe. The course seems to be a great introduction to aspiring astrophysicists, and does a great job of explaining and testing the core concepts.

I've read many articles that talk about the relevance of these courses on a CV/Résumé, and most come to the conclusion that it is "better than nothing", or it is simply "coursework on a CV/Résumé.

My question is, would completing a sequence of online courses related to the same material be more appropriate to be included in a CV? For example, Australian National University is offering 4 core courses on Astrophysics (The Greatest Unsolved Mysteries of the Universe, Exoplanets, The Violent Universe, and Cosmology). For those interested, you might find this useful:
https://courses.edx.org/c4x/ANUx/ANU-ASTRO1x/asset/Combined_Syllabus.pdf

These four courses together form a single certification in Astrophysics.
Anyone can complete a single course and list them on their CV. But, completing 4 courses in the same subject shows a dedication towards learning, and also self-motivation. Also, the one who completes these doesn't risk résumé padding because the 4 courses would form one point on a CV, not two.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE! This seems to me a straight duplicate of [a](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/3312/73) [few](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2336/73) [questions](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1317/73). Unless I'm missing something, the only differentiating factor here is that you also state your own opinion. I don't know what else there is to add here that hasn't already been said.

Comment: At a more basic level, specific coursework generally doesn't belong on a CV.