# Do online courses and certificates actually count toward University credits?

Tags: online-learning, online-degree, certification

I am interested in pursuing a couple of online courses and certifications but I am not sure if they will count towards my university credits or in getting a job. I found some courses from this [article](http://www.webemployed.com/best-free-online-courses-certificates-in-2017/) but i need to make sure that they will actually be beneficial for me. They also have mentioned a couple of online degrees from University of People. Does it count as an accredited degree worldwide?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the value of a Coursera certificate?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/21526/what-is-the-value-of-a-coursera-certificate), [Does one get academic credit towards a degree for open online courses?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1317/does-one-get-academic-credit-towards-a-degree-for-open-online-courses). Related; [Are verifiable MOOC programs of study recognised by employees?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32822/are-verifiable-mooc-programs-of-study-recognised-by-employers)

Comment: For your last question: There is no guarantee that anything will count as an accredited degree worldwide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your online sources are accredited, and your certifications are germane to the work you will be asked to do, then absolutely they will help you get the job you desire. But, since degrees are bestowed by Universities, only they can determine what (and whose) credits are transferable. My first year was spent at a community college (for personal reasons), but even so, I had to have my (desired) academic path laid out, to avoid wasting time on unnecessary courses. Of course, some classes are taken for the sheer joy of attaining knowledge, but know your goal, and keep it in mind. 
I looked at your link provided, and note with interest that the University of California accepts some credit transfers for 'exceptional' students. I would verify statements like that, tho' I'm not disputing it. These courses seem to be for a 'leg up', which is good if they help you be in the top of your class. But I don't believe that is what you are asking.